# Same query, different costs [BigQuery]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table with daily partitions by the `triggered_at` (timestamp) column.
When writing a query in the Google cloud console, it is possible to see the costs of processing.

Today I noticed such an anomaly. I wrote a query using where clause on the `triggered_at` field, the cost was 4.49 GB. Then I accidentally added whitespace character to my query and the cost decreased = 163.63 MB.
After that I could repeat the action and the cost constantly changed.
For the sake of interest, I tried two more ways of using where clause and the cost dropped dramatically and did not change anymore (14.27 and 11.85 MB).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to execute the first version of the query a couple of times.
As a result, on job information tab I could see bytes processed/bytes billed, and they were:

```
first attempt = 3.35 GB 
second attempt = 3.37 GB
third attempt = 1.31 GB (maybe already cached)
```

Actually there are two questions:

1. why adding just whitespace character affects costs?
2. why is there such a serious difference between options:

   `date(triggered_at, 'Europe/Moscow') = date'2023-10-01'`

   `triggered_at = timestamp'2023-10-01 00:00:00+0300'`

   `triggered_at = '2023-10-01'`

I assume that my table is partitioned by UTC time and in case of switching to the Moscow timezone the BigQuery optimizer checks more than one partition. But why do the costs not change in the second case?

Answer (score -1):

I have replicated your inquiry but on my side it looks like bytes processed does not changed even adding whitespaces. (Probably I have a smaller data?)

No White space:
[image]

With White Space
[image]

Also if its cached it will display with the value bytes billed:

[image]

By default you are billed by [on demand](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing/#on_demand_pricing) pricing model, meaning you will be billed by the data scanned for your queries. There are few factors that might affect the billing bytes such as partitioned/clustered tables, tuned where clauses for specific scanning and more ( that may be listed to the documentation linked above)

As for the white spacing can you try highlighting the whole query(ctrl a) if the price still changes with white spaces ? Possibly an issue in the project that might be the best action is to file support case to Google to have to better look at your project and backend: